# Azure Devops VS Test Failing The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops

My unit test run successfully locally but when I run it through the VSTest step in my pipeline I get the following failure.

threw exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AutoFixture, Version=4.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b24654c590009d4f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF

and

threw exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PriceListManagement.Integration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

(PriceListManagement.Integration is a .Net framework project)

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Pipline Yaml Below

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*UnitTests*.dll
     **\*.IntegrationTests*.dll
```

Comment: Did you restore packages? Please share with us your pipeline definition.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Pipeline Yaml added :)

Comment: Hi @RichardWatts. You could check if the answer below could give you some help. If no, you can also try to run the pipeline on  the [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) and check if it could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my project files were pointing at .Net Framework version 4.6.1
When I pointed the project files at .Net Framework version 4.7.2 and upgraded some the necessary nugets the pipeline passed :-)

Comment: Great ! You could accept this answer. It will be helpful to other users. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Could not load file or assembly 'AutoFixture, Version=4.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b24654c590009d4f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This problem could be related to the project dependencies specified in `xxx.csproj` file.

You can check if you have referenced the problematic .dll file (AutoFixture,PriceListManagement.Integration).

For example:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.2.1.2\lib\net48\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

If yes, you need to check if the **HintPath** contains the target file.

For AutoFixture:

You can specify the corresponding package in the **package.config** file

Package.config

```
<packages>
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="AutoFixture" version="4.14.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

.Csproj file HintPath:

```
<HintPath>..\packages\AutoFixture.4.14.0\lib\net452\AutoFixture.dll</HintPath>
```

For PriceListManagement.Integration

Since it is a project dependency, you need to determine whether the generated .dll is in the corresponding path.

On the other hand, based on your yaml template, this seems to be a standard build process. It could work successfully.

Comment: Kevin Many thanks for the reply, unfortunately it has not solved my problem. For AutoFixture the relative path in the "HintPath" is correct and it already appears in the package.config.

The project reference hint path for PriceListManagement.Integration also looks correct, and it is referenced by another test project which runs fine on the pipeline. I am at a loss :-(